# How to create a stream that emit a value only when another stream emit a value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm learning rxjs.
Assume I have an array of value:

```
[12, 23, 34, 56, 78, 99]
```

I want to create a stream `A$` of the above values, but it don't emit values one after another **immediately**, instead it should wait to emit value only when another stream `B$` emits a value.

Comment: Where would it get data from?

Comment: just plain array defined manually, not from ajax call or other kind of async operation.

Comment: http://rxmarbles.com/#sample ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options :

- use `sample`, as mentioned in the comments to your question. This means that you will not have access to the value emitted by `B$`.
- use `combineLatest`/`zip` if you want to reuse the value carried by your stream `B$`, and some additional semantics. For instance, `A$.combineLatest(B$, function (a,b){...})`
- `withLatestFrom`, but like this : `B$.withLatestFrom(A$, function (b,a){...}`

All these options have slightly different semantics, so choose them wisely.